# I'm trying to search and display data and if possible, in another page

Tags: php

Im trying to display the data in my .txt file, my data is not display neither is there an error message. Please help!

```
<form method="post" action="">
                <input type="text" name="carplate"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
            </form>
<?php       
if(!empty($_POST['carplate'])) {
                $file = 'carListingDB.txt';
                $searchfor = '';
                // the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
                header('Content-Type: text/plain');
                $searchfor = $_POST['carplate'];
                $contents = file_get_contents($file);
                $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
                $pattern = "/^.$pattern.\$/m";
                if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
                   echo "Found matches:\n";
                   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
                   echo file_get_contents( "carListingDB.txt" );
                }

                else{
                   echo "No matches found";
                }
                header('Content-Type: text/html');
                } 


?>
```

I want to display the data and if possible in another page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming this is all of the code, there will be no `$_POST['carplate']`.  You've also not put php tags around your PHP code

try looking for the submit button array element in the `$_POST` global.

```
<form method="post" action="">
     <input type="text" name="search"/>
     <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
if(!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
            $file = 'carListingDB.txt';
            $searchfor = '';
            // the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
            header('Content-Type: text/plain');
            $searchfor = $_POST['carplate'];
            $contents = file_get_contents($file);
            $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
            $pattern = "/^.$pattern.\$/m";
            if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
               echo "Found matches:\n";
               echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
               echo file_get_contents( "carListingDB.txt" );
            }

            else{
               echo "No matches found";
            }
            header('Content-Type: text/html');
 } 
?>
```

I cant guarantee that theres nothing else wrong in your actual PHP, but this should get you at least a bit futher.

Comment: Hi DevDonkey! In my actual codes, it is within the php tags.

Answer (score 0):

I've rearanged your code a little. I've changed pattern for `preg_match_all()`

```
?php
if (!empty($_POST['carplate'])) {
    $file = 'carListingDB.txt';
    $searchfor = '';
    $searchfor = $_POST['carplate'];
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
    $pattern = "/^.*${pattern}.*\$/mi";
    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)) {
        header('Content-Type: text/plain');
        echo "Found matches:\n";
        echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
        echo "\n\n";
        echo "File's content:\n";
        echo file_get_contents($file);
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "No matches found";
    }
}
?>
<form method="post" action="" target="_blank">
  <input type="text" name="carplate"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

The sample content of file *CarListingDB.txt*

```
audi a6
audi a4
audi mini
escudo v6
escudo v4
vitara
```

The one example of successfull request - `audi`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to display the results out by changing the following

```
$pattern = "/^.$pattern.\$/m";
```

to

```
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
```